# Array manipulation based on input

Tags: arrays, c

I ran into a problem when working on a project, and mananged to track the issue down to this point:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void printme(char *data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%c ", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    char data[9]; for(int i=0;i<9;i++){data[i]='0';}
    char in[2];

    printme(data);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &in[i]); getchar();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("in[%d] = %d\n", i, in[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        data[in[i]] = 'X';
    }

    printme(data);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to use the input I get as an index for array `data`. It doesn't seem to be working though, printing `0`s regardless of what I enter. What could I be missing?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why did you use `getchar`?

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula Since I am taking multiple inputs, I need to consume the newline character. Otherwise, the next `scanf()` will simply take in the newline instead of my desired input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

1. Switch from `char` to `int`: `int in[2];` instead of `char in[2];`
2. Scan a number, not a character

Your code working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printme(char *data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%c ", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    char data[9]; for(int i=0;i<9;i++){data[i]='0';}
    int in[2];

    printme(data);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &in[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("in[%d] = %d\n", i, in[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        data[in[i]] = 'X';
    }

    printme(data);

    return 0;
}
```

If for whatever reason your are forced to use `char` then you need to subtract the ASCII value:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printme(char *data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%c ", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    char data[9]; for(int i=0;i<9;i++){data[i]='0';}
    char in[2];

    printme(data);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        scanf(" %c", &in[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("in[%d] = %d\n", i, in[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        data[in[i] - '0'] = 'X'; // this transforms ASCII char to his 
                                 // integer representation
    }

    printme(data);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome, also notice the space before `%c` in order to consume the trailing newline instead of `getchar()`

Comment: I see. A space looks cleaner than a `getchar()`. Thanks for the tip!